# ASP.NET - Accessing copied content

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class library project which contains some content files configured with the "Copy if newer" copy build action.  This results in the files being copied to a folder under `...\bin\` for every project in the solution.  In this same solution, I've got a ASP.NET web project (which is MVC, by the way).  In the library I have a static constructor load the files into data structures accessible by the web project.  Previously I've been including the content as an embedded resource.  I now need to be able to replace them without recompiling.  I want to access the data in three different contexts:

1. Unit testing the library assembly
2. Debugging the web application
3. Hosting the site in IIS

For unit testing, `Environment.CurrentDirectory` points to a path containing the copied content.  When debugging however, it points to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE`.  I've also looked at `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` which points to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c44f9da4\9238ccc\assembly\dl3\eb4c23b4\9bd39460_f7d4ca01\`.  What I need is to the physical location of the webroot `\bin` folder, but since I'm in a static constructor in the library project, I don't have access to a `Request.PhysicalApplicationPath`.

Is there some other environment variable or structure where I can always find my "Copy if newer" files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Assembly.Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx) does indeed point to the location of the assembly after it has been shadow copied.

However, that MSDN page states:

> To get the location before the file has been shadow-copied, use the [CodeBase property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.codebase.aspx).